# Primus Inter Non Pares

Tags: riddle, enigmatic-puzzle

Looking around inside an antique shop, I come across an old hand mirror. 
I pick it up and notice something written on its edges.
Carved on it are the words below.

> Effortful list freaks esteemed at specially prescribed figures, imply me

Can you figure out what this means?

Comment: Translated from Latin, the title is "Between the first non parent".

Comment: @Duck are you sure -  "Primus Inter Pares" is "First among equals" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primus_inter_pares), so wouldn't it be something like "First among unequals" ?

Comment: @Duck as racraman pointed out, "First among unequals" is the intended meaning of the title. I realize that it is grammatically incorrect given that "non" is used with verbs but I hoped the meaning would come across.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you

> take the second letter of each word

you get

> first prime

Which is

> 2, which is first among [non]equals?